# isset && Count result from db

Tags: codeigniter, count, isset

I want to show a table if the vpn information isset but its notworking. Its showing a empty table with no username and pass. Instead of there are no vpm's setup yet.

A picture is here :

Code : http://snag.gy/kxB6r.jpg
result : http://snag.gy/EfdOW.jpg

( im using codeigniter )

Comment: Its better to show your code here directly, and your results

Comment: I dont know how to edit the question, and its to long for in a comment. a friend of my use  {if (isset($VPN)) && $VPN|@count > 0}  But i cant use {} in my html thats why i try to conver it to php.

Comment: is vpn a result from a query ? in this case you've to write $vpn->num_rows() > 0 instead of count($vpn) > 0

Comment: copy and paste your code into your question.  Highlight it.  Then find the button at the top of the edit window like this: {}  Press it

Comment: Try with `count($vpn->result)` instead of `count($vpn)`.

Answer (score 0):

use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
if(!empty($vpn)){
   echo "Have data"
}
else{
   echo "No data";
}
```

> This will act as `isset` and `count>0`

Comment: Empty is not working either. Thats why i tried to count it :S